# ios scrollIndicatorInsets won't go beyond scrollview bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I want to put scrollViewIndicator just a bit more outside(right) of scrollView. But It doesn't go even if I set `self.mainMenuCollectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);`. It might because of **inset** works as **padding** and not going out of bounds of scrollView. It stays in the border.

It **works** for putting indise(left) of the view.

It would be really helpful if you know how can I achieve that.

N: normal
S: It is possible
W: How I want

[image]

Comment: The scroll indicators are *subviews* of the scroll view, so you cannot move them outside (they wouldn't be visible). They have a default inset of 3.5 (if I remember correctly), so if you want them *right along the edge* you can use `-3.5` on your edge insets.

Comment: If indicator wasn't be visible, I would have check for make some views clearColor so that I could show it. But in my case, it is still visible on the edge even tho I give them 50p inset. I can still see it.

Comment: Hmmm... not clear what you're asking then... you say *"bit more outside(right) of scrollView"* -- do you mean you want the indicator to be further **inset** from the right edge?

Comment: Could you please check my marvellous art piece for explanation of what I want? I edited my question with a picture.

Comment: `UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 30);` should give you `S`. `W` is only possible if you set `clipsToBounds = NO` on your scroll view, but... then *all* content of the scroll view is visible outside its bounds.

Comment: Yeah `S` is possible but I want to do `W` which I couldn't do it with `clipsToBounds = NO`.

Comment: Your best bet for `W` is probably to inset your content in the scroll view. I think that's the only way to give you the appearance you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup opposite side with minus sign like:

```
self.mainMenuCollectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: -10)
```

Don't forget disable clipsToBounds for getting visible subviews outside:

```
self.mainMenuCollectionView.clipsToBounds = false
```